# Could not resolve host '(localdb)' on Visual Studio for MacOS

Tags: sql, asp.net, macos, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Developing an Asp.Net web Api working with SQL. I'm stuck at debugging app on my Mac. When calling methods, working with db, app returns instead this error:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Could not resolve host '(localdb)'

Feels like a mistake is somewhere in this line (according to other answers): Web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDatabaseContext-12.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This app works perfectly fine in VS for Windows. Any ideas?

Update: I have an sql server in azure, so I have a connection string. Any way to make it used instead of local?

Comment: localdb doesn't exist for mac.  You can install LocalDB in a Windows Docker container, or on a VM running on the mac.  SQL Server 2017 can also be installed on mac.