# .NET Core 2.0 connection string for Mac and PC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I've just started working on a .NET Core 2 project. I am using a Mac while the other developers are on Windows PCs. However there are some problems with SQL Server on Mac. First, SQL Server does not run on Mac. That can be worked around by running SQL Server in a local docker container: https://medium.com/@reverentgeek/sql-server-running-on-a-mac-3efafda48861

Second problem is that LocalDB, which is used in most tutorials and for local development/testing does not work for mac either, as stated here [Could not resolve host '(localdb)' on Visual Studio for MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613431/could-not-resolve-host-localdb-on-visual-studio-for-macos).

My question is, what is a good way of loading the correct connection string for PC or Mac in Development? I was thinking about adding multiple strings like so but not sure what is best practice.

appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=myWindowsDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "MacConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=myMacDb;User Id = someuser;Password=mySecretMacPassword;Initial Catalog = myMacDb;"
},
```

Comment: If all the developers are on the same network, you can simply set up SQL Server on one machine and access it by all developers. This way the connection string will be exactly the same for everybody and changes to the database don't need to be copied to all machines, so it guarantees that they all are using the same database version. In this scenario, simply change `(localdb)` and `localhost` to the IP of the database server.

Comment: Sounds like you might instead want to make use of development level app settings that each individual dev can customize for their environment.

Comment: Or you could read the connection string from an environment variable. You can customize the config system to read in environment variables and have those take precedence over values from the appsettings files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is just for your own individual dev environment you shouldn't make any changes to `appsettings.json` in your project to work around it. Instead, you can create a separate `appsettings.Development.json` file containing:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=myMacDb;User Id = someuser;Password=mySecretMacPassword;Initial Catalog = myMacDb;"
}
```

And ASP.NET Core will load it by default after `appsettings.json` and override and previous values read in. I would keep this file out of source control and use it for individual developer settings.